# Randomly receiving empty emails via PHP script

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner helping my aunt build a personal website. I have an HTML form where users can contact her (slightly simplified for clarity):

```
<form id = "contact-form" method = "post" action = "contact-form-handler.php">
<input name = "name" type = "text" required><br>
<input name = "email" type = "email" required><br>
<textarea name = "message" class = "form-control" required></textarea><br>
<input type = "submit" class = "form-control submit" value = "SEND MESSAGE">
</form>
```

The script `contact-form-handler.php` reads,

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = "SEND_EMAIL@ADDRESS.com";

    $email_subject = "Message from fziastories";
    $email_body = "Name: $name.\n".
        "Email: $visitor_email.\n".
        "Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "RECIEVE_EMAIL@ADDRESS.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

This form works great. When I enter various tests, the message goes through perfectly. And when I don't enter a value for one of the three inputs, I am not able to hit the 'SEND MESSAGE' button.

Except, every once in a while, maybe once or twice a week, I receive an empty message with no values filled out. This is confusing to me because I figure the current setup precludes users from submitting the form without entering value but also through the tests I have ruled out the possibility that a valid response is being entered as blanks.

I would greatly appreciate any advice! If you have any follow-up questions, do not hesitate to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Realize that one doesn’t have to go through your form to **send an HTTP request with arbitrary content** to your server. Frontend validation is never enough, ultimately you need to validate in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `required` tag in HTML forms is not very secure!
You should always validate the data on your server.

This could look something like this:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];


    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
       header("Location: index.html");
       exit;
    }

    $email_from = "SEND_EMAIL@ADDRESS.com";

    $email_subject = "Message from fziastories";
    $email_body = "Name: $name.\n".
      "Email: $visitor_email.\n".
      "Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "RECIEVE_EMAIL@ADDRESS.com";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
    mail($to,$email_subject, $email_body, $headers);
    header("Location: index.html");
?>
```